Clarifying a step in the Lindeberg approach to the central limit theorem
For context, ${X_1,X_2,\dots}$ are iid copies of a scalar random variable ${X}$ of zero mean and unit variance, and $G: {\bf R} \rightarrow {\bf R}$ is a smooth compactly supported function. Writing $\displaystyle {Z := \frac{X_1 + \dots + X_{n-1}}{\sqrt{n}}}$. From math-275A-note-4, one step in the Lindeberg approach to the central limit theorem proceeds by using the Taylor approximation
$\displaystyle G( Z + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} X_n ) = G(Z) + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} G'(Z) X_n + \frac{1}{2n} G''(Z) X_n^2 + O( \frac{1}{n^{3/2}} |X_n|^3 )$
where the implied constant depends on ${G}$.
My question concerns the error term. Taylor expanding $G$ around $Z$ gives
$\displaystyle G( Z + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} X_n ) = G(Z) + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} G'(Z) X_n + \frac{1}{2n} G''(Z) X_n^2 + \frac{1}{n^{3/2}} X_n^3 \sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{G^{(3+i)}(Z)}{(3+i)!} (\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}X_n)^i$,
so it seems we need $\displaystyle \sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{G^{(3+i)}(Z)}{(3+i)!} (\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}X_n)^i = O(1)$ where the implied constant depends on $G$. Some small assistance in clarifying this derivation will be appreciated.

The Taylor theorem with remainder gives:
$$
    G\left(Z + \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}}X_n\right) = G(Z) + \dfrac{X_n}{\sqrt{n}}G'(Z) + \dfrac{X_n^2}{2n}G''(Z) + \dfrac{X_n^3}{6n^{3/2}}G'''(\epsilon_n)
$$
where $\epsilon_n$ is some random variable lies between $Z$ and $Z + \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}}X_n$. Since $G$ is a smooth compactly supported function, $\vert G'''(\epsilon_n) \vert$ is bounded almost surely, that is
$$
    \vert G'''(\epsilon_n) \vert \le \sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}} \vert G'''(x) \vert < \infty, \text{ a.s}
$$
Therefore,
$$
   G\left(Z + \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}}X_n\right) = G(Z) + \dfrac{X_n}{\sqrt{n}}G'(Z) + \dfrac{X_n^2}{2n}G''(Z) + O\left(\dfrac{\vert X_n \vert^3}{n^{3/2}}\right)
$$

Thank you, somehow this elementary formula skipped from my consideration. Also, I believe you have $2n$ for the denominator of $X_n^2$ in the first display.

@shark yes, you are correct
